# Encoding of site in iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, encoding, character-encoding

I have a script on jquery that load some site in iframe using:

```
$("#demo_frame").attr('src', 'http://'+url);
```

My page have a charset UTF8, but if loaded site have another charset - in i frame it's have bad encoding.

How can i set right encodyng to site in iframe?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header in the Iframe has to do this for itself.

Comment: Which type is declared in the iframe doc?

Comment: Will the page load normally outside of the iframe?